# Finding x,y coordinates where y is largest

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following list of $x,y$ coordinates:

```
A = {{-5, 0.508928}, {-4, 0.516564}, {-3, 0.523614}, {-2, 0.523574}, {-1, 0.520759}, {0, 0.519357}, {1, 0.502434}, {2, 0.505553}, {3, 0.510231}, {4, 0.515214}, {5, 0.517549}}
```

Now, I wish to find the $x,y$ coordinate, where $y$ is largest. I have tried:

```
A // MatrixForm
Max /@ Transpose[A]
```

But this returns the combination of maximum in each column.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
MaximalBy[A, Last]
```

> {{-3, 0.523614}}

Answer (score 7):

```
A[[Ordering[A[[All, -1]], -1]]]
```

> {{-3, 0.523614}}

Note: `Ordering` typically is faster than alternatives for large lists.

```
SeedRandom[1]
a = RandomReal[1, {100000, 2}];
r1 = a[[Ordering[a[[All, -1]], -1]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0017

```
r2 = First[SortBy[a, -Last@#&]];// RepeatedTiming// First
```

> 0.017

```
r3 = TakeLargestBy[a, Last,1]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.039

```
r4 = MaximalBy[a, Last]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.065

```
r5 = First[Sort[a, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]];// RepeatedTiming// First
```

> 1.88

```
r1 == {r2} == r3 == r4 =={r5}
```

> True

Comment: Thinking about this, I am somewhat shocked how ineffcient `MaximalBy` is.

Comment: @Henrik, me too.

Answer (score 2):

```
First[Sort[A, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]]
```

> {-3, 0.523614}

Answer (score 2):

Another simpler one:

(*sort the list by last element of each sublist and then pick the last element*)

```
SortBy[A, Last][[-1]]
```

Which gives `{-3, 0.523614}`

Comment: You mean `SortBy[A, Last][[Length[A]]]`? How about  `SortBy[A, Last][[-1]]` or `Last@SortBy[A, Last]`

Comment: Oh!, yes! Thanks, included yours!.